# Is it possible to deploy multiple bundles to ServiceMix that use Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, apache-karaf, hibernate-envers, apache-servicemix

We are attempting to deploy multiple bundles in ServiceMix 6.1.4 that each make updates to a database and we want those updates to be audited with Hibernate Envers 4.3.6.FINAL. We are in the proof-of-concept stage, so we are only building the jar files and putting them into the deploy directory of the apache-servicemix-6.1.4 directory, with a separate datasource blueprint file for each.

Individually, the bundles work and audit just fine. But if you have both bundles deployed, one will fail with the error:

```
2018-04-20 14:00:10,635 | WARN  | mix-6.1.4/deploy | container                        | 260 - org.apache.aries.jpa.container - 1.0.2 | Error creating EntityManagerFactory
org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistrationException: Duplicate event listener found
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.listenerShouldGetAdded(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:143)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.appendListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.appendListeners(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerRegistryImpl.appendListeners(EventListenerRegistryImpl.java:172)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:84)[254:org.hibernate.envers:4.3.6.Final]
    at Proxy7c321f84_ab1f_4b15_a78a_66080ada210e.integrate(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)[251:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)[251:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)[252:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)[251:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:112)[253:org.hibernate.osgi:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.createEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:336)[260:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.registerEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:239)[260:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.bundleStateChange(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:182)[260:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleManager.modifiedBundle(PersistenceBundleManager.java:301)[260:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4403)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2092)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1243)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1215)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:506)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:355)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:307)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
```

I created two simple bundles that can reproduce the issue based on the standard managed-jpa example code.

First pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>managed-jpa-test1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.enterprise</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.console</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version> 
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.hibernate.osgi.managed-jpa-test1</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>managed-jpa-test1</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
            <Private-Package>
              org.hibernate.osgitest,
              org.hibernate.osgitest.entity
            </Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>
              org.hibernate.jpa,
              org.apache.felix.service.command,
              org.apache.felix.gogo.commands,
              org.apache.karaf.shell.console;resolution:=optional;version="[3.0,4)",
              org.apache.karaf.shell.commands;resolution:=optional;version="[3.0,4)",
              javax.persistence;version="[1.0.0,2.1.0]",
              <!-- Needed for proxying's Javassist enhancement during runtime -->
              org.hibernate.proxy,
              javassist.util.proxy,
              *
            </Import-Package>
            <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Second pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>managed-jpa-test2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.enterprise</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.console</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version> 
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.hibernate.osgi.managed-jpa-test2</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>managed-jpa-test2</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
            <Private-Package>
              org.hibernate.osgitest2,
              org.hibernate.osgitest2.entity
            </Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>
              org.hibernate.jpa,
              org.apache.felix.service.command,
              org.apache.felix.gogo.commands,
              org.apache.karaf.shell.console;resolution:=optional;version="[3.0,4)",
              org.apache.karaf.shell.commands;resolution:=optional;version="[3.0,4)",
              javax.persistence;version="[1.0.0,2.1.0]",
              <!-- Needed for proxying's Javassist enhancement during runtime -->
              org.hibernate.proxy,
              javassist.util.proxy,
              *
            </Import-Package>
            <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

First blueprint.xml:

```
<blueprint default-activation="eager"
           xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

  <bean id="dpService" class="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointServiceImpl">
    <jpa:context unitname="managed-jpa-test1" property="entityManager"/>
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required"/>
  </bean>
  <service ref="dpService" interface="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointService"/>

    <bean id="integrator" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator" />
    <service ref="integrator" interface="org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator" />

  <command-bundle xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0">
    <command>
      <action class="org.hibernate.osgitest.command.AddCommand">
        <property name="dpService" ref="dpService"/>
      </action>
    </command>
  </command-bundle>
</blueprint>
```

Second blueprint.xml:

```
<blueprint default-activation="eager"
           xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

  <bean id="dpService2" class="org.hibernate.osgitest2.DataPointService2Impl">
    <jpa:context unitname="managed-jpa-test2" property="entityManager2"/>
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required"/>
  </bean>
  <service ref="dpService2" interface="org.hibernate.osgitest2.DataPointService2"/>

    <bean id="integrator" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator" />
    <service ref="integrator" interface="org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator" />

  <command-bundle xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0">
    <command>
      <action class="org.hibernate.osgitest2.command.AddCommand2">
        <property name="dpService2" ref="dpService2"/>
      </action>
    </command>
  </command-bundle>
</blueprint>
```

DataPoint.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class DataPoint {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

DataPoint2.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class DataPoint2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

First persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="managed-jpa-test1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=test1/mssql)</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Second persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="managed-jpa-test2" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=test2/mssql)</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

DataPointService.java:

```
public interface DataPointService {

    public void add(DataPoint dp);

}
```

DataPointServiceImpl.java:

```
public class DataPointServiceImpl implements DataPointService {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void add(DataPoint dp) {
        entityManager.persist( dp );
        entityManager.flush();
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

}
```

AddCommand.java:

```
@Command(scope = "dp1", name = "add")
public class AddCommand implements Action {
    @Argument(index=0, name="Name", required=true, description="Name", multiValued=false)
    String name;

    private DataPointService dpService;

    public void setDpService(DataPointService dpService) {
        this.dpService = dpService;
    }

    public Object execute(CommandSession session) throws Exception {
        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
        dp.setName( name );
        dpService.add( dp );
        return null;
    }

}
```

DataPointService2.java:

```
public interface DataPointService2 {

    public void add(DataPoint2 dp);

}
```

DataPointService2Impl.java:

```
public class DataPointService2Impl implements DataPointService2 {

    private EntityManager entityManager2;

    public void add(DataPoint2 dp) {
        entityManager2.persist( dp );
        entityManager2.flush();
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager2() {
        return entityManager2;
    }

    public void setEntityManager2(EntityManager entityManager2) {
        this.entityManager2 = entityManager2;
    }

}
```

AddCommand2.java:

```
@Command(scope = "dp2", name = "add")
public class AddCommand2 implements Action {
    @Argument(index=0, name="Name", required=true, description="Name", multiValued=false)
    String name;

    private DataPointService2 dpService2;

    public void setDpService2(DataPointService2 dpService2) {
        this.dpService2 = dpService2;
    }

    public Object execute(CommandSession session) throws Exception {
        DataPoint2 dp = new DataPoint2();
        dp.setName( name );
        dpService2.add( dp );
        return null;
    }

}
```

datasource-test1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="test1DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XXXX;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true;uselobs=false"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value="XXXXX"/>
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="test1DataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="test1/mssql"/>
        </service-properties>
    </service>
</blueprint>
```

datasource-test2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="test2DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XXXX;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true;uselobs=false"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value="XXXXX"/>
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="test2DataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="test2/mssql"/>
        </service-properties>
    </service>
</blueprint>
```

I think that is all the relevant files. Probably more than I need, but better safe than sorry.

We want to be able to offer the bundles as separate solutions that a customer can use depending on their needs. Like one HL7 bundle and a WebService bundle and so forth.

If it is only possible to have one bundle using Envers, then we will have to develop an additional bundle that does the database updates, but it would be better if the bundles could be self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

You are offering the envers extension using

```
<bean id="integrator" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator" />
<service ref="integrator" interface="org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator" />
```

As this is an OSGi service it will be picked up by all bundles. So the bundle that starts last will see both and complain. Try to put this in its own bundle to make sure it is only registered once.

Comment: So, in essence, the answer is no? It can't be done inside the individual bundles, we'll need a separate bundle to register this service?